# Symfony Assert validation with yaml

Tags: symfony, validation, yaml

I have mapped my entity with yaml and I'm using the assert to add some constraint for certain field.

So I follow the documentation and put my validation in this file:

`# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml`
it works...

But I want to separate my validation. I need one file for one entity.

So I did it that way:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation/DeliveryAddress
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation/BillingAddress
```

But it does not seem to work that way.

Here one of my file:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation/DeliveryAddress.yml
AppBundle\Entity\DeliveryAddress:
    properties:
        address:
            - NotBlank: ~
        zipCode:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Regex:
                pattern: '/^[0-9]{5}$/'
                match: false
                message: 'Le code postal que vous avez saisi n’est pas valide'
        town:
            - NotBlank: ~
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: ~
        lastName:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The lines that start with '#' are **comment lines** in YAML, are you sure this is loaded and interpeted by Symfony? Have you tried just to change `# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml` to `# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/notthere.yml` and check if that prohibited things from loading.

Comment: I know @Anthon it was just a example to show you where did I put my file, I'm gonna update my post

Answer (score 0):

This works natively since symfony 2.7
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/13855

The problem was because match was to false

```
zipCode:
   - NotBlank: ~
   - Regex:
       pattern: '/^[0-9]{5}$/'
       match: false
```